# Genexus 16 - Chatbot no contesta los mensajes (a veces)

Tags: genexus

El problema que he tenido en los últimos días es que a veces el Chatbot de Genexus no me responde. A veces le digo 'Hola' o algún otro mensaje definido en el Conversational Flow y es como que Chat no reaccionara. El chat funciona correctamente sino que a veces simplemente se queda.

El mensaje escrito por mí si se guarda, pero el Chatbot no reacciona dado cierta condición que no puedo detectar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando **Genexus 16 U7.** Lo estoy utilizando con **IBM Watson Assistant** con **IAM Authentication.** (Api Key)
Por favor necesito ayuda para saber donde puedo ver el error que se está generando.

Comment: Puedes prender el log a nivel del generador. Log Level = All y User Log Level = All. Después de la ejecución fallida verifica el log en el archivo client.log de tu environment. Ahí deberías poder ver algo de info... si hubo un error o si ni siquiera sale el mensaje

Comment: @sebagomez Te comento que si me ha servido tu sugerencia. Aparentemente el response JSON del Watson tenía un caracter no válido y lo pude corregir. Hasta ahora no ha ocurrido nuevamente el error. Te agradezco.